# loading window application forms based on Query executed

Tags: c#

I have a two form Loginform  and Setupform. if user is yet to setup the necessary parameter login form should be hide on Application.Run(new login()); and Application.Run(new Details()) should show

```
private void countmem1()
    {
        sqlconnect conss = new sqlconnect();
        conss.Connections();
         SqlCommand gold = new SqlCommand("select Address, Name from Detail where USER_name='admin'", conss.con);
        SqlDataReader srd = gold.ExecuteReader();
        if (srd.Read())
        {
          
            this.Show();
            
        }
        else
        {
            this.Close();
            DETAILS f2 = new DETAILS();
            f2.Show();
            //MessageBox.Show("USER DOESN'T EXIST");
        }
    }
```

Comment: this.Close() makes no sense.  You need to close the instance of either Loginform or Setupform.  Clsing will close the class being run and f2.Show() will never occur.

Comment: hi @Lawrence, 

I suggest you separate your DB logic from the app logic, create a UserExists method that returns a boolean, and based on this determine the behavior of your forms. If you're only using the SQL to know if the user exists, then you could do "select top 1 1 from Detail where user = @piUser" then bind user to a SqlParameter, thanks.

Comment: I appreciate you all, problem solved